# using tinylog 2.0

Tags: android, tinylog

I try to use tinylog 2.0 on android, and I have a problem.
Logger prints that error:

```
LOGGER WARN: No logging framework implementation found in classpath. Add tinylog-impl.jar for outputting log entries.
```

But in gradle file I have

```
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog-api:2.0.0-M3'
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog-impl:2.0.0-M3'
```

I don't use proguard, and flag minifyEnabled is false in Gradle

I found out that application can't load classes, because it can't find them. I don't understand, why classes are not in APK file

Comment: You'll probably have more luck asking this question on the projects github issues page.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Martin where to add the tinylog.properties file? I added in project root folder but not working.

Comment: @Kameswari You can put tinylog.properties in 'src/main/resources' if you have a Maven or Gradle project. See https://tinylog.org/v2/configuration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In tinylog 2.0.0-M3, there was a bug that caused a wrong class loader to be used for loading tinylog's service files. This bug was reported in another context as [issue #96](https://github.com/pmwmedia/tinylog/issues/96) and is fixed with tinylog 2.0.0-M4.

Just update your dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog-api:2.0.0-M4'
implementation 'org.tinylog:tinylog-impl:2.0.0-M4'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working now. Is there any way to set the file path dynamically?

Comment: @Kameswari Yes, you can set the path to tinylog.properties via the system property "tinylog.configuration" or load any configuration dynamically via tinylog's Configuration class.